# How to divide odd matrix into cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

consider i have an odd matrix with dimension:

```
x = <349*385 double>
```

and then i do this following step:

```
order = [1 9 2 3 10 17 25 18 11 4 5 12 19 26 33 ...
         41 34 27 20 13 6 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 57 50 ...
         43 36 29 22 15 8 16 23 30 37 44 51 58 59 52 ...
         45 38 31 24 32 39 46 53 60 61 54 47 40 48 55 ...
         62 63 56 64];
x = double(x);

y = im2col(x, [8 8],'distinct');
xb = size(y, 2);
y = y(order, :);
y = y(:)';
```

I get y :

```
y = <64x2156 double>
xb = 2156;
y = <1x137984 double>
```

and I transform y into cell :

```
for i=1:length(x)
    r{i} = y(floor((end/length(x))*(i-1)+1):ceil((end/length(x))*i));
end
```

finally i reverse r into matrix :

```
y1 = cell2mat(r);
```

I get y1 :

```
y1 = <1x138308 double>
```

My question is why y1 can't get the same result with y? I want y1 and y same. Maybe i wrong when dividing matrix y into cell r. Please help me.

Comment: did you check the sizes of `x`, and those "early" steps of `y, xb`? Could you post those sizes (edit your question). My guess is, that `y=im2col(...)` results in another length than `length(x)` which later on results in a misdimension errror in your for-loop. Because you use `length(x)`there which is not padded with zeros.

Comment: i have edited, so how to code to make the same result of y1 and y> @TheMinion

Comment: following your definition of `r`, i guess r has the length of 1x134365 (349*385). So it missmatches from `length(y)=1x137984`. Which is less than `length(y1)=1x138308`. Honestly I am unsure what you are trying to do by converting `y`to cell and back to matrix. Two things you could do: Do not convert arrays out of `y` into cells in `r` and secondly you could pad your `x` with zeros so it fits your dimension. I would try giving you an answer but I do not fully get the idea behind your code, so I have no chance to work on my own solution

Comment: IF you succeed to solve your problem pls post your solution for future visitors.

Comment: I still don't know actually @TheMinion